# MySQL - SUM() query results over multiple timestamps

Tags: sql, mysql, grafana

I have some data like this

| Used | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-03-12 12:30:04 |
| 0 | 2023-03-12 12:30:04 |
| 1 | 2023-03-12 12:30:04 |
| 1 | 2023-03-12 12:30:04 |
| 0 | 2023-03-12 12:30:54 |
| 0 | 2023-03-12 12:30:54 |
| 1 | 2023-03-12 12:30:54 |
| 0 | 2023-03-12 12:30:54 |

What I would like to do is generate a sum of 'used' for all distinct timestamps - although even better would be distinct + 10 seconds to catch any where the cronjob was slightly delayed in writing to DB

My rather basic SQL knowledge can take care for any given timestamps

```
SELECT sum(used),timestamp  
FROM usage  
WHERE timestamp = '2023-03-12 12:30:04'
```

and I reckon I could write something in powershell to do the aggregation if I had to, but I'm sure there must be a nice clean easy way to do this in MySQL

Expected output

| sum(Used) | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-03-12 12:30:04 |
| 1 | 2023-03-12 12:30:54 |

Ultimately I'd be using this data in grafana so either getting to the output in mysql or grafana would both be viable

Thanks

Comment: Remove `WHERE` but add `GROUP BY timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to aggregate the data. Here you want to aggregate the data for each timestamp.

Check the query.

```
SELECT 
    sum(used), timestamp
FROM 
    usage  
GROUP BY 
    timestamp
```